# How to type "raw" bopomofo/zhuyin without converting to hanzi characters in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, typing, chinese, ime

Windows 7 comes with a variety of IMEs for entering Chinese in the manner used in Taiwan known as "bopomofo" or "zhuyin".

Like other IMEs their main job is to convert from a small set of characters to the large set of Chinese characters.

But occasionally there is a need to create text strings in bopomofo itself. To avoid the conversion step into characters.

I've played with several of the IMEs and did some Googling on the subject but have not found a way to do this. The zhuyin is always converted to hanzi!

Answer (score 0):

Start that section by holding down the Shift key for the first character. This should give you the desired result.

Comment: No, when I try this I just get uppercase English letters. I'm using the "New Phonetic" IME version 10.1. But I can use another if this doesn't support it.

Comment: I assume you release the Shift key after typing the first letter?

Comment: If I hold down the shift key and press a key that would normally result in a bopomofo character and then release the shift key I get a double-wide uppercase English letter instead.

Comment: Ahh, then you have it set for "in-text English" input. Just change it to Chinese and you should be fine.

Comment: How do I "just change it"? Do I have to go into the settings or is there some key or combination I can press while typing to switch back and forth? (Such as shift, caps lock, ctrl+shift, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Press the space key and then the enter key after typing each bopomofo character.

Comment: From memory, some apps capture the enter key as an actual enter and not just selecting a candidate from the IME. Annoying but it means it's not safe to do across all apps. Then again it's over a year and a half since I was in Taiwan typing Bopomofo so I'm now pretty rusty on how things were at the time.